# can i apply QOS for the attached network diagram?

Tags: networking, router, qos

is it possible to apply QOS for the attached network diagram? all traffic passes through the gateway pc. i want to know if the QOS policies i created on this pc controls all the traffic that comes from other computers on the LAN.

thank you[image]

Comment: What is running on the gateway PC?

Comment: WIndows 7 ultimate edition 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

The gateway PC could in theory apply QoS policies to all the traffic that passes through it, which in this case would be any traffic to/from the Internet (via the modem), but not local LAN traffic amongst the wired and wireless LAN devices.

Whether or not the gateway/QoS software on your gateway PC supports doing that is a different matter.